# Remove empty new line in spring boot java reactor slf4j exception log

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j

Do anyone know how to remove empty new line between error log and error stacktrace everytime the system logging exception? This case only happening on services that using spring boot 2 with java reactor, and the empty new line log is only happening when the service is running, when the same line of code run through unit test there is no new empty line added between error log and error stacktrace. This is causing the service's log on splunk chunked and not recognized as 1 event of log.

I'm using default version of SLF4J from the current Spring Boot version I use, the slf4j-api version is 1.7.30

Here is the code I use to test it :

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/error-handler")
public class ErrorHandlerController {

  @RequestMapping(
      value = "/_test-error-log",
      method = RequestMethod.GET,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
  )
  public Mono<Response<String>> testErrorLog() {
    String param1 = "value1";
    String param2 = "value2";
    String param3 = "value3";
    String param4 = "value4";
    String testValue = null;
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> ResponseHelper.ok(testValue.concat("random word")))
        .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("param1 : {}, param2 : {}, param3 {}, param4 : {}, error : ", param1, param2, param3, param4, throwable))
        .onErrorReturn(ResponseHelper.ok("error response"));
  }

}
```

Here is the error log sample :

```
2020-06-11 18:58:08.116 ERROR [fraud-aggregator,,,] 34204 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.g.f.a.web.ErrorHandlerController     : param1 : value1, param2 : value2, param3 value3, param4 : value4, error : 

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.gdn.fraud.aggregator.web.ErrorHandlerController.lambda$testErrorLog$7(ErrorHandlerController.java:195) ~[classes/:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:56) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1705) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1705) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:296) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1705) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1705) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:247) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:329) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1705) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:61) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2267) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2075) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1949) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:64) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:228) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:465) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:90) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:170) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.5.RELEASE.jar:0.9.5.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321) ~[netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295) ~[netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
```

Expected error log format :

```
2020-06-11 18:58:08.116 ERROR [fraud-aggregator,,,] 34204 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.g.f.a.web.ErrorHandlerController     : param1 : value1, param2 : value2, param3 value3, param4 : value4, error : 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.gdn.fraud.aggregator.web.ErrorHandlerController.lambda$testErrorLog$7(ErrorHandlerController.java:195) ~[classes/:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:56) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1705) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
.....
```

Comment: Which Slf4j implementation are you using?

Comment: I am using this one
`public void error(String format, Object... arguments);`
because I need to log more than 3 arguments value, and the last arguments is Throwable class